# Android Virtual Device Manager - Can not start virtual device missing Kernel file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Recently I have installed latest Android Studio. I have created android virtual device, but i can not run it. It gives following error in Android Studio Event log:

```
11:06 AM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-ranchu" is in the same location as your system image.
11:06 AM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is defined (D:\Android\SDK) but cannot find kernel file in D:\Android\SDK\system-images\ sub directories
11:06 AM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am on Windows 10. I tried various suggestions on the web but none has worked for me. Maybe someone has similar experience? How Can i make android emulators run on?

My virtual device configuration looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: Try running your virtual device on the x86 version of the apk, like android studio is recommending you.

Comment: @HartWoom Thank you. I have changed AVD Target from Android 4.4 to Android 4.4 (Google APIs) And the device started to work and i even run my application successfully on it. I do not fully understand why i had to change target. Maybe you could provide some information around this?

Comment: I don't have a full answer on this, but my guess is, since an emulator depends on the system it runs (in your case windows) there are different version of an APK in order to run them on different platform. Those versions only differs in what systems it supports, and windows has probably a different kernel than a smartphone running android kitkat, explaining why you had this error about the kernel not found.